# Simulating a keypress using capybara-webkit in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-tokeninput, capybara-webkit

I'm using capybara-webkit to test a form where the fields are populated using jquery-tokeninput (https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput). The problem is that using fill_in does not work with this. Is there anyway to test this automatically? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

https://github.com/markgandolfo/send-keys

## Send the 'a' character to the input who's id is search (#search)

And I send a to "input#search"

## Send the 'a', 'b' and 'c' characters to the input who's id is search (#search)

And I send abc to "input#search"

## You can put them in quotes if you feel more comfortable

And I send 'abc' to "input#search"

## You can also send modifier/special key strokes to an element

And I send arrow_left to "input#search"

## You can even send a combination of modifier and characters

## This will result in a the character 'A' being sent to the input

And I send [shift, a] to "input#search"

## Or maybe you just want to press enter

And I send enter to "input#search"

## How cool would it be to test the counter in a text area (say for a twitter app)

And I send hello to "#message"
And I should see "135" in "characters_left"
And I send backspace to "#message"
And I should see "136" in "characters_left"

## We used it to test completion suggestions

## The first suggested name was highlighted and responded to an enter keypress

And I send "bo" to "input#username"
And I should see "bob" within "username_suggestions"
And I send enter to "input#username"

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this only works using selenium webdriver, not capybara-webkit

Answer (score 0):

I have been using token input also, and what it does is that it hides your actual input field, and replaces it with another element with an id matching `token-input-{your_field_id}`. So say you have a field with the id `search`, you should in fact target the element with the id `token-input-search`.

So an example code snippet would be:

```
fill_in "token-input-search", with: "hello"
```

And you can test you behaviour afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

From the release notes in the capybara-webkit code, they have this entry from the 1.0.0 release:

```
* Set text fields using native key events.
```

So, it looks like setting the text on the text field is going to cause the native events to fire.

Like you, I also needed this to work and found that this did the trick:

```
find('input#query').set 'some text'
```

My javascript picked up the `keyup` event that it was listening for and fired the way it should.